# Uploading and saving files using django nonrel in Google App engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, file-upload, django-nonrel

According to the official django documentation about uploads, small files are saved to memory and big files are saved to disk.

I would like to know how to save uploaded files to disk? Is it possible?

This is my code so far. But it only works on memory. When I try to write the file to disk, or the file is big in size the app crashes.

**views.py**

```
# ...
def spreadsheet_form(request, id = None):
    if is_admin_user(request):
        instance = get_object_or_404(Spreadsheet, id=id) if id is not None else None
        form = SpreadsheetForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            spreadsheet = form.save(commit=False)
            spreadsheet.name = request.POST['name']
            spreadsheet.spreadsheet_file = request.FILES['spreadsheet_file'].name
            spreadsheet.size = request.FILES['spreadsheet_file'].size
            spreadsheet.save()
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['spreadsheet_file'])
            return redirect('/spreadsheets/')
        return render_to_response("pages/spreadsheet_form.html", {"form": form,"id":id},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return redirect('/', False)
# ...
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open(f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

**models.py**

```
# ...
class Spreadsheet(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    spreadsheet_file = models.FileField(upload_to='spreadsheets/')
    size = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name )
```

**settings.py**

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",
)
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 7000000
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as 'save to disk' in the App Engine world.  The closest was Blobstore, and now it's GCS.

django-nonrel includes a django storage class to upload to Blobstore.  Follow this:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/06/Uploads-to-Blobstore-and-GridFS-with-Django

You don't need to fiddle with the FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS, the defaults are fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I found this useful documentation also:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers#installation

It looks like the datastore is not the best option for saving files. Likely it has to be done via blobstore, or some other external location. Eg: AWS S3